# How to get libtool to statically link dependencies of a shared library

Tags: mingw, automake, libtool

I'm preparing some patches for libFLAC, a lossless audio codec library. In the past, libFLAC has always been provided to windows users as a single DLL, with its dependency (libogg) embedded. This was no problem when compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio.

I'm trying to patch the autotools/libtool build system to do something similar with MinGW, but I don't seem to be able to do that. I've tried the following things:

The following apparently tries to link with both static and shared libssp

```
LIBS="-Wl,-static -lssp" ./configure; make all V=1
[...]
libtool: link: gcc -shared  .libs/bitmath.o .libs/bitreader.o .libs/bitwriter.o .libs/cpu.o .libs/crc.o .libs/fixed.o .libs/fixed_intrin_sse2.o .libs/fixed_intrin_ssse3.o .libs/float.o .libs/format.o .libs/lpc.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse2.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse41.o .libs/lpc_intrin_avx2.o .libs/lpc_intrin_vsx.o .libs/md5.o .libs/memory.o .libs/metadata_iterators.o .libs/metadata_object.o .libs/stream_decoder.o .libs/stream_encoder.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_sse2.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_ssse3.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_avx2.o .libs/stream_encoder_framing.o .libs/window.o .libs/windows_unicode_filenames.o .libs/ogg_decoder_aspect.o .libs/ogg_encoder_aspect.o .libs/ogg_helper.o .libs/ogg_mapping.o   -L/mingw64/lib -logg -lssp  -O3 -msse2 -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-static   -o .libs/libFLAC-8.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libFLAC.dll.a
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0\libssp.a(ssp.o):(.text+0xe0): multiple definition of `__stack_chk_fail'; C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libssp.dll.a(d000009.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

In the following try, nothing really happens: the resulting DLL still has dependency on libssp-0.dll

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-static -lssp" ./configure; make all V=1
libtool: link: gcc -shared  .libs/bitmath.o .libs/bitreader.o .libs/bitwriter.o .libs/cpu.o .libs/crc.o .libs/fixed.o .libs/fixed_intrin_sse2.o .libs/fixed_intrin_ssse3.o .libs/float.o .libs/format.o .libs/lpc.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse2.o .libs/lpc_intrin_sse41.o .libs/lpc_intrin_avx2.o .libs/lpc_intrin_vsx.o .libs/md5.o .libs/memory.o .libs/metadata_iterators.o .libs/metadata_object.o .libs/stream_decoder.o .libs/stream_encoder.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_sse2.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_ssse3.o .libs/stream_encoder_intrin_avx2.o .libs/stream_encoder_framing.o .libs/window.o .libs/windows_unicode_filenames.o .libs/ogg_decoder_aspect.o .libs/ogg_encoder_aspect.o .libs/ogg_helper.o .libs/ogg_mapping.o   -L/mingw64/lib -logg -lssp  -O3 -msse2 -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-protector-strong   -o .libs/libFLAC-8.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libFLAC.dll.a
```

Next, the -static flag seems to be intercepted and compilation of shared objects is not done at all

```
CFLAGS="-static" ./configure; make all V=1
```

Finally, the last example, the -static flag is not intercepted, but compilation of shared objects is not done at all

```
CC="gcc -static" ./configure; make all V=1
```

Also, using LIBS="-l:lssp.a", which works fine with CMake, gives me the following error:

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -l:libssp.a.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have
*** because I did check the linker path looking for a file starting
*** with lib:libssp.a and none of the candidates passed a file format test
*** using a file magic. Last file checked: /mingw64/lib/libogg.dll.a
*** The inter-library dependencies that have been dropped here will be
*** automatically added whenever a program is linked with this library
*** or is declared to -dlopen it.
```

I got this to work by using `make V=1`, copying the used linker command and rerunning it with `-static` added. It seems to me this should be possible without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Some older `libtool` files don't properly detect `.dll` files, for example if they are to know to know 64-bit Windows `.dll` file signatures.

Sometimes regenerating autoconf files with `autoreconf` may fix that.

If you are sure you have all the files needed (`.a`, `.dll.a`, `.dll`) you can change `libtool` to not check if these files actually exist.
To do that run the following after running `./configure` and before `make`:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\(deplibs_check_method=\"\)[^\"]*/\1pass_all/" libtool
```

Comment: Are your sure it's none and not pass_all? That seems to work with LIBS="-l:libssp.a" at least

Comment: @ktmf Not checking or always passing the checks, what's the difference? Both should work, buy maybe not checking is slightly faster...

Comment: If I use pass_all building works as expected, if I use non I get

Warning: inter-library dependencies are not supported in this platform.
All declared inter-library dependencies are being dropped.
The inter-library dependencies that have been dropped here will be
automatically added whenever a program is linked with this library
or is declared to -dlopen it.

Since this library must not contain undefined symbols,
because either the platform does not support them or
it was explicitly requested with -no-undefined,
libtool will only create a static version of it.

Comment: Okay, then `pass_all` it should be. I updated my answer above.

Comment: This fixes the last warning, but not the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution proposed by Brecht Sanders, the problem is solved by changing the libtool script after it is generated by configure. It is not a nice solution, but it does work.

Changing `archive_cmds="\$CC -shared [...]` to `archive_cmds="\$CC -static -shared [...]` enabled building of a shared library while statically linking dependencies.